# Mayan EDMS install, seems ok, but not working

Tags: linux, ubuntu, installation, server, mayanedms

[image]

I follow the steps on the below link, and build it on my ubuntu cloud, it seems ok, but not working on my browser.
https://mayan.readthedocs.io/en/v2.1.4/topics/installation.html

no matter on local: http://127.0.0.1:8000/ 
or on my cloud server: http://***.**.55.12:8000/

Can anyone help? I found less information on the internet about this EDMS.

Comment: Install `lynx` and then in another terminal type the following command: `lynx http://127.0.0.1:8000` and post the output....

Comment: @Hackerman alert!: Unable to connect to remote host

Comment: @Hackerman still not working, am I lack of web potocol?

Comment: And `lynx http://localhost:8000`?

Comment: @Hackerman the same message, alert!: Unable to connect to remote host

Comment: But...you need to run the command in the same server that runs mayan

Comment: @Hackerman Thanks! It can browse on my cloud server, but also cannot be browse by others, cannot find the way to resolve the problem. Now I use its deploying way to build, it's working now.

Comment: Locally runs, but it can't be browse from another machine inside the same network....is that the issue now?

Answer (score 0):

The address 127.0.0.1 (or localhost) is a loopback address and only accesible to the same host only.

From the installation instructions:

> Note that the default IP address, 127.0.0.1, is not accessible from other machines on your network. To make your test server viewable to other machines on the network, use its own IP address (e.g. 192.168.2.1) or 0.0.0.0 or :: (with IPv6 enabled).

use:

```
./manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

[Installation instructions](http://mayan.readthedocs.io/en/v2.1.5/topics/installation.html)

Comment: Thank You! Sorry I didn't look very clear on the steps, I try this way, but it also cannot view by other network. Now I try its deploying way to build, it's ok now.